# Problems with Scala Iterator vs. Java Iterator (a casting nightmare): How to cast to Java from Scala?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

What I am trying to accomplish is simple:
Return the list containing a Tuple2 as a Java Iterator.

The code snippet is:

```
....public java.util.Iterator<Tuple2<Path, Text>> call(InputSplit inputSplit, java.util.Iterator<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>> iter) throws Exception { 


    .....  java.util.List<Tuple2<Path, Text>>  elements = new java.util.ArrayList<Tuple2<Path, Text>>();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Tuple2<LongWritable,Text> tupled = iter.next();
            Tuple2<Path, Text> toAdd = new Tuple2<Path, Text>(file.getPath(),tupled._2);
            elements.add(toAdd);
        }
        java.util.Iterator<Tuple2<Path, Text>> it = elements.iterator();
        return it; .....}
```

Note: the variable `iter` is also a Java Iterator.

The error I get is:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr cannot be cast to scala.collection.Iterator`

1. What am I doing wrong? (I am aware that I am using `Tuple2`, which is meant for Scala).
2. How do I return a Java Iterator with a `Tuple2` or a `Tuple2` equivalent ?

Thank you

Comment: What is you method signature?

Comment: public java.util.Iterator<Tuple2<Path, Text>> call(InputSplit inputSplit,
     java.util.Iterator<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>> iter) throws Exception {

... PLEASE NOTE: I must return a JAVA iterator

Comment: You should edit your question to add this information, it's easier to read. What line give you this error?

Comment: WIll do.  The line java.util.Iterator<Tuple2<Path, Text>> it = elements.iterator(); ---gives the error

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're doing an illegal cast from Java iterator to Scala iterator.

Try using [scala.collection.JavaConversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$).
When you import this implicit class - these conversions will be done automatically.

In short -

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

Another option is to do it explicitly, assuming `javaIterator` is your java iterator -

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
javaIterator.asScala
```

Comment: Thank you, I would like to ask where exactly to use it, since the error appears in the line:::

java.util.Iterator<Tuple2<Path, Text>> it = elements.iterator(); ::: I have tried casting it at the end (at the return) and it did not work.  EDIT: OK I have some idea... will let you know.

Comment: As I said you shouldn't cast. You should: `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` and it will do the conversion for you implicitly

Comment: still the same problem, but thank you for answering. I will try to cast the collection first, then get the Scala iterator, then cast it back to Java, just for fun.

Comment: Edited my comment. Please retry. Don't try to cast it - it won't work.

Comment: If you prefer to do this explicitly you can `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._` and then javaIterator.asScala

Comment: Perhaps your solution(s) will work for someone else. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Maxim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/375022/maxim) answer is correct, here is exact java code which will do conversion:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;
List<String> javaBatch = new ArrayList<String>();
scala.collection.Iterable<String> scalaBatch =  JavaConversions.asScalaIterable(javaBatch);
```

Similarly, method `JavaConversions.asScalaIterator()` can be used for iterators. Vice-versa is also possible.