# convert scala list to java list

Tags: java, scala

I tried to convert scala list to java list via the following snippet code:

```
 val obj=Array("aaa","bbb")
 val output = obj.asInstanceOf[java.util.ArrayList[String]]
```

But I got the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList.
Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429944/how-to-convert-a-scala-list-to-a-java-util-list

Answer (score 1):

You can't use cast because these are DIFFERENT types.

Scala provides you with classes to convert between Java <-> Scala collections

An implicit way - [import scala.collection.JavaConversions._](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$)

An explicit way - [import scala.collection.JavaConverters._](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$)

Also you can see my answer to a similar question here - [Problems with Scala Iterator vs. Java Iterator (a casting nightmare): How to cast to Java from Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629763/problems-with-scala-iterator-vs-java-iterator-a-casting-nightmare-how-to-cas/29631243#29631243)